# please prove Dom(h) = Dom(f)∪Dom(g)

Tags: functions

Let f : A →B and g : C → D be two functions such that *f(x)* = *g(x)*, ∀x∈A∩C.
Then the union *h* of *f* and *g* defines the function *h* = *f*∪g : A∪C → B∪D

where

*h(x)* = *f(x)* if *x*∈A,

*h(x)* = *g(x)* if *x*∈C
.

I wanna know Dom(h) = Dom(f)∪Dom(g) = A∪C.
I think it can be possible intuitively, but I don't know how to prove this by math symbols.

I got Dom(h) ⊆ A∪C, but couldn't prove A∪C ⊆ Dom(h)

Comment: How is $h$ defined if $A\cap C\neq\emptyset$? If on this intersection $f$ and $g$ do not coincide then the union $f\cup g$ cannot be recognized as a function. Or is $h$ not necessarily a function here?

Comment: h is need not be a function. actually, i'm in the process of proving h is a function
(defining Dom(h) + (x,y)∈f ∧(x,z)∈f then y=z)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general if $h\subset U\times V$ then the domain of $h$ can be
defined as the set of elements $u\in U$ for wich there is an element $v\in V$
such that $\left(u,v\right)\in h$.

Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ be a function. That means actually that $f\subset A\times B$
and for each $a\in A$ there is a unique $b\in B$ with $\left(a,b\right)\in f$.
Here $A$ is the domain of $f$. Let $g:C\rightarrow D$ be a function
too. Then $g\subset C\times D$, and $h:=f\cup g\subset\left(A\cup C\right)\times\left(B\cup D\right)$
is a function if and only for each $x\in A\cap B$ we have $f\left(x\right)=g\left(x\right)$
(which is vacuously true if $A\cap B=\emptyset$). This because the
$h\left(x\right)\in B\cup D$ with $\left(x,h\left(x\right)\right)\in h$
must be unique. If the condition is satisfied then $A\cup C$ can
be recognized as the domain of function $h$. If the condition is
not satisfied then $h$ is not a function but still it can be looked
at as a subset of $\left(A\cup C\right)\times\left(B\cup D\right)$.
Its domain is $A\cup C$ since if and only if $x\in A\cup C$ we can
find an $y$ such that $\left(x,y\right)\in h$. Here $y=f\left(x\right)$
is $x\in A-C$, $y=g\left(x\right)$ if $x\in C-A$ and $y$ can take
both values $f\left(x\right)$ and $g\left(x\right)$ if $x\in A\cap C$.